# Ícone customizado jquery mobile intel xdk

Tags: html, css, jquery-mobile, intel-xdk

Não estou conseguindo colocar um ícone customizado no meu header! Alguém pode ajudar?

html:

```
<a data-role="button" class="icon-myicon" data-icon="myicon"></a>
```

css:

```
.ui-icon-myicon{
  background-image: url("icons/IconMenuPrincipal.png");
}
```

Comment: Bem-vindo ao Stack Overflow! Recomendo fazer um [tour](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/tour) para saber mais em como obter boas respostas. Poderia nos fornecer mais detalhes? Por exemplo: a imagem não aparece? Ocorre algum erro? O que já tentou? Como está a estrutura de diretórios do seu projeto?

Comment: Cara, é muito complicado. Eu também não consegui fazer isso. única coisa que me ajudou, foi pegar ícones da versão 1.4.5, baixar e colocar dentro da pasta img do site.